# Error processing run file with bcl2fastq - Unable to open '.../RunInfo.xml' file for reading

Tags: illumina, demultiplexing

I'm attempting to demux a nextseq run which I've successfully done several times in the past on other runs. I uploaded the run from my PC to the server (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) without issue. Then I ran:

````
```bcl2fastq --runfolder-dir /data/201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF --sample-sheet ./SampleSheet.csv  --no-lane-splitting --barcode-mismatches 0```
````

From which I got the error:

> ````
> '/data/201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF/RunInfo.xml' file for
> reading```
> ````

However, the RunInfo.xml file is present and readable:

```
$ ls -l
total 96
drwxrwxrwx 10 user user 90112 Nov 11 08:08 201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF
-rwxrwxr-x  1 user user 1929 Nov 11 07:37 SampleSheet.csv
$ 
$ ls -l 201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF/RunInfo.xml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 28510 Nov 11 08:08 201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF/RunInfo.xml
$ 
$ head 201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF/RunInfo.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="4">
  <Run Id="201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF" Number="128">
    <Flowcell>H5G5KBGXF</Flowcell>
    <Instrument>NB551126</Instrument>
    <Date>201109</Date>
    <Reads>
      <Read Number="1" NumCycles="75" IsIndexedRead="N" />
      <Read Number="2" NumCycles="6" IsIndexedRead="Y" />
    </Reads>
```

Has anyone had this issue or know of a fix? Thanks!

Update: contents of run folder

````
total 2452
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart   977 Nov 11 07:59 '2020-11-09__14_05_58_94F12309 GetBestZ Camera 1 Focus Red top surface.snr.csv'
....
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart   244 Nov 11 07:59 '2020-11-09__14_08_54_FE05AB9F SafeParabola called by CalculateSignalStd.snr.csv'
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart   253 Nov 11 07:59 '2020-11-09__14_08_54_FE0620BC SafeParabola called by FindPeakUsingParabolaFit.snr.csv'
....
drwxrwxrwx 2 stewart stewart  4096 Nov 11 07:59  Config
drwxrwxrwx 3 stewart stewart  4096 Nov 11 07:59  Data
drwxrwxrwx 3 stewart stewart  4096 Nov 11 08:07  Images
drwxrwxrwx 2 stewart stewart 12288 Nov 11 08:07  InstrumentAnalyticsLogs
drwxrwxrwx 2 stewart stewart  4096 Nov 11 08:08  InterOp
drwxrwxrwx 2 stewart stewart  4096 Nov 11 08:08  Logs
drwxrwxrwx 2 stewart stewart  4096 Nov 11 08:08  Recipe
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart    48 Nov 11 08:08  RTAComplete.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart  6200 Nov 11 08:08  RTAConfiguration.xml
drwxrwxrwx 2 stewart stewart  4096 Nov 11 08:08  RTALogs
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart    36 Nov 11 08:08  RTARead1Complete.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart    36 Nov 11 08:08  RTARead2Complete.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart   925 Nov 11 08:08  RunCompletionStatus.xml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart 28510 Nov 11 08:08  RunInfo.xml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart 26802 Nov 11 08:08  RunParameters.xml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 stewart stewart  1929 Nov 11 08:08  SampleSheet.csv```
````

Comment: What does `ls -l /data/201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF/` give?

Comment: It was too long for a comment so see update above. Interestingly there are a lot of .csv files I'm not used to seeing but the files that should be there are present as far as I can tell!

Comment: I've got it .. just a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repro the error.

```
ls /ml
```

> ls: cannot access '/ml': No such file or directory

If run

```
bcl2fastq --runfolder-dir ./data/201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF --sample-sheet ./SampleSheet.csv  --no-lane-splitting --barcode-mismatches 0
```

I suspect it will work.

At present you are attempting to call a directory `/data`, which doesn't exit. If you type `ls /etc` that will work. The difference between `./data` and `/data` in a file structure is alot, but on a command line it appears minimal.

---

Wait ... if that doesn't work .. because I suspect the calling directory is `data` then the following will,

```
bcl2fastq --runfolder-dir ./201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF --sample-sheet ./SampleSheet.csv  --no-lane-splitting --barcode-mismatches 0
```

OR

```
bcl2fastq --runfolder-dir ./data/201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF --sample-sheet ./data/SampleSheet.csv  --no-lane-splitting --barcode-mismatches 0
```

It depends on the path where you are making the call. You could sort this out using `$PWD` or just `echo $PWD` then copy and paste the path name.

Comment: Such a simple fix! Thanks for your solution. I simply ran this from the folder containing the folder and it worked: ```bcl2fastq --runfolder-dir 201109_NB551126_0128_AH5G5KBGXF --sample-sheet SampleSheet.csv  --no-lane-splitting --barcode-mismatches 0```